# Android | Google Maps V2 | Scale Bar / Ruler

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2

The Google Map application by default shows a ruler/scale-bar which appears when we zoom-in/zoom-out the map. I want to show a similar ruler in the android application I am building. I am using Google Map V2, but there does not seem to be any api available. Please let me know if I am missing something or there is some other way to accomplish the same.

Answer (score 0):

It's not available for devleopers in API. You must implement this yourself.